# Ubuntu grub loader does not show up

Tags: boot, grub

When I try to boot into Ubuntu I get this screen. I selected Ubuntu but id did not boot, instead it simply refreshed the menu.

Answer (score 2):

There is a setting in `/etc/default/grub` called `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden` which prevents the GRUB menu from showing during the timeout period unless you press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. Check to see if this setting is enabled by `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden`, and if it is enabled open the `/etc/default/grub` file for editing in nano text editor and disable it.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Comment out the line that says `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden` by preceding it with a `#` character. Make sure that the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` value there is set to a value larger than zero, for example `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10`. Save the file.

Then run the `update-grub` command and reboot:

```
sudo update-grub  
sudo reboot
```

<sub>**Nano text editor keyboard shortcuts**</sub>
<sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file to its current location.</sub>
<sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.</sub>

Other useful links

- [How to repair GRUB2 when Ubuntu won't boot](https://www.howtogeek.com/114884()/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/)
- [Using EasyBCD to boot to GRUB from Windows boot menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139966/how-can-i-add-an-entry-for-ubuntu-to-the-windows-7-boot-menu/140376#140376)
- [Installing GRUB2 Ubuntu documentation wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2)
- [Dual-boot boot menu does not show up after installing Ubuntu 15.10 alongside Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/q/717904)